# What exactly is the standard graphic card supported by QEMU?

Tags: qemu

Does QEMU emulate an Intel integrated graphic chip for its `vga std` option? Is there a specification for such device e.g. a document with the programming interface?

Comment: Are you trying to design your own OS or what?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Yes. For the basic VGA, it's ok. Now I want to understand how VGA works by reading some official document. But the standard vga from QEMU gives little information.

Comment: QEMU simply emulates the plain old VGA standard.  If you want to know how a VGA driver looks like, you might want to look at the Xorg source code but your question is still awfully vague.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am confused with the standards. For each CPU model, we have a different datasheet e.g., x86_64 and ARM are given different datasheets. Is this the case with graphic cards, or are they using the same VBE standard, even until now?

Comment: It's the same with graphics cards, even more so nowadays since graphics cards host GPUs (but QEMU doesn't emulate those). There are some common "standards" which all PC graphics cards support, VGA being the highest guaranteed common denominator in terms of hardware (registers etc.), VESA the highest in terms of "API" (VBE provides a set of functions to switch graphics modes etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QEMU [emulates a Cirrus CLGD 5446 PCI card](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#pcsys_005fintroduction). It's VGA and VESA 2.0 compatible, so you can use any [VGA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array), [VESA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions) or 5446 documentation...

Comment: But what is the different between `cirrus` and `std`? While Cirrus has a datasheet, what is the datasheet of `std`?

Comment: Standard VGA is IBM's original VGA, which is documented in its Technical References (such as the [VGA/XGA Technical Reference](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_ibmpccardseferenceManualMay92_1756350)). The Cirrus card is a "SuperVGA" card with more memory and higher resolutions and colour-depth.